# Can not install bootstrap in angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a new angular project, and I want to install bootstrap styling there. So I runned the following command:

```
>npm install --save bootstrap
```

but this is what I have received:

```
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <
5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.
0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents)
:
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3:
wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ bootstrap@3.3.7
added 116 packages in 10.308s
```

I checked in node-modules folder but I didn't found the bootstrap folder. I checked in google and I found that it might be an issue in angular. How can I fix that?

I share with you my `package.json` file, it can help finding the solution:

```
{
  "name": "source-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using webpack setup rather that angular cli, you could just include stylings in vendor file, eg `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`, also double check, it looks that it *was* installed, perhaps your IDE haven't refreshed files or you've missed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of bootstrap styling in angular, try including bootstrap from a CDN like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
```

in the head tag of your corresponding html file or the `index.html` itself (in case you want full visibility).
You can then use bootstrap classes for your html elements!

Hope this helps.

Comment: even it is the answer of what I am looking for, but it seems a great solution for my instant problem

Answer (score 3):

- npm install jquery --save
- npm install bootstrap --save
- Add css and js files for jquery and bootstrap in .angular-cli.json file

  ```
  "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]

  "styles": [
   "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ]
  ```
- Now ng serve

Answer (score 1):

The Angular (when you use Angular CLI) way of adding bootstrap to your project is to add the library (in your case the css) to the `.angular-cli.json` file.

If you also need the js, remember to include this in your `scripts` in your `.angular-cli.json`.

An example of how this is done, under your styles array add:

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Full snipit can be seen here:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

If you cannot find your bootstrap folder, try refreshing the workspace folders. This can be done on the round arrow in the navigator in VS Code if that's your editor.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards Chris

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above methods don't know it didn't work for me

open the file "src/styles.css" and add the following line of code

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

I hope it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. But when I closed and re-run my text editor (in my case vs code). I was able to find the bootstrap folder in the node_modules folder.

May be this helps.

Or else you can use bootstrap by a cdn link in index.html file.